# How to retrieve/get data from Firebase DB Ionic and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to do crud operation using Ionic and Firebase. So far I am able to create record in Firebase Db. I am trying to retrieve the list for displaying.

my Code is as follows:

/*homepage.ts*/

```
export class HomePage {
  userList$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private _userService: UserListService) {

  }
ionViewDidLoad(){
   this.getUser();
 }


  public user: User = {
    FirstName: 'text',
    Lastname: 'Kumar',
    Email: 'amanGandey@gmail.com',
    PanNm: 'AmAnsjfdgs',
    AdhaarNm: '12311223411'
  }

  addUser() {
    this._userService.addUser(this.user).then(ref => {
      console.log(ref.key)
    })
  }

  getUser() {
    this.userList$ = this._userService.getUserList().snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
      }))
    })

  }
}
```

/*Service.ts*/

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { User } from '../../models/user/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class UserListService{
private userListRef = this.db.list<User>('user-list');

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){

    }
    getUserList(){
        return this.userListRef;
    }
    addUser(user: User){
        return this.userListRef.push(user);
    }
}
```

/*HTML*/

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Users
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let user of userList$ | async"></ion-item>
    {{user.FirstName}}
  </ion-list>
```

/*model*/

```
export interface User {
    key?: string;
    FirstName: string;
    Lastname: string;
    Email: string;
    PanNm: string;
    AdhaarNm: string;
}
```

I am not able to retrieve the user list from firebase DB.
Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please create a StackBlitz project if possible.

Comment: Is there any error or just blank array?

Comment: cannot read property Firstname of undefined